# How to define bourbon and neat in grunt js file / windows 8 user?

Tags: gruntjs, bourbon, neat

I'm trying to use this code and I get error for using "loadPath" duplicated.

```
 options: {
           style: "compressed",
           sourcemap : true,
           loadPath: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
           loadPath: require('node-neat').includePaths
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using node-neat will return an array of the paths for both Bourbon and Neat. Try this:

```js
options: {
  style: "compressed",
  sourcemap : true,
  loadPath: require('node-neat').includePaths
},
```